# No aparecen los estilos CSS al subir a Github Pages

Tags: html, css, imagen, github, github-pages

La página que estoy creando es un blog, que tiene varias páginas las cuales TODAS cargan las fotos y el CSS perfecto, excepto por el "About me" que carga el CSS pero no las fotos. He probado de todo, lo cual ha hecho que mi codigo este un poco mas desordenado...

Y desde el index no funciona el link al "About me"

[Página](https://santiago-ruberto.github.io/Descubri-entre-rios/)

[Repositorio](https://github.com/Santiago-Ruberto/Descubri-entre-rios)

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres con que no te muestra las imagenes:/, intenta poner una captura en tu pregunta, y explicarte más respecto a tu problema preguntando cuál es el resultado que esperas, qué has intentado, y qué no te funciona. Saludos.

Comment: Tus imágenes no están cargadas o están mal definidas en el html, lo cual puedes ver [Aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuTeO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionan en los comentarios efectivamente no están siendo encontrada las rutas correctas en el archivo perfil.html

Solución:
Para evitar futuros problemas con rutas simplemente puedes colocar el 'relative path' que lo obtienes posicionandote en donde esta tu imagen, click derecho -> 'Copy Relative Path'.
Te adjunto la documentación [HTML File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)
Y los cambios que realicé en mi local, espero te sean de ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]